# Como salvar os dados de uma grid que foram alterados?

Tags: php, mysql, extjs

> Meu sistema possue uma grid com itens do pedido, vindo do banco de
>   dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem, preciso alterar os itens pedido, acrescentar mais um item ou até mesmo remover.
Recebe as informações em json e coloco-as na grid. 
Consigo interagir na `JsonStore`, que é um array dos itens, removo e adiciono normalmente, mas isso de forma local.

Bem, finalizado a edição dos itens do orçamento, preciso ennviar para o banco de dados as edições feitas.

Nesse momento eu preciso de ajuda.

> Existe um padrão de modelagem no sql para realizar esse procedimento?
>
> Qual a melhor maneira? Deleto tudo no banco relacionado aos itens do
>   orçamento e insiro novamente? Faço um update nos itens?

Se precisar de mais clareza na pergunta por favor me avisem.

Comment: Amigo não sou expert porém vou deixar minha opnião, no caso da atualização dos dados modificados, creio eu que um UPDATE terá um melhor desempenho, tambem pensei numa opção de você conseguir uma forma de saber os que foram editados ou não...dessa forma você poderia da um update apenas nos modificados..espero que lhe dê alguma luz.

Comment: Estes campos que estão no filtro acima da tabela, ela está relacionada com alguma outra tabela ou ela é uma tabela unica ? tipo tem 2 tabelas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que vou propor, não está baseada na sua linguagem (php) e sim no seu problema.

Pelo seu printscreen, eu entendi que **1** Pedido possui **N** ItemPedidoDeProduto (que contem o codigo do produto, a quantidade ...) que contem **1** referência para o Produto. Estamos falando aqui de **1 -> N -> 1**

Toda vez que enviar os dados para o servidor, você deve enviar e recuperar o id do **Pedido**, e partir dele, recuperar todos os **ItemPedidoDeProduto**.

**Atualização dos ItemPedidoDeProduto**

Você deve usar o id deles que virão de um campo hidden para fazer a comparação com o que já está cadastrado no banco.

**Remoção de um ItemPedidoDeProduto**

Compare os ItemPedidoDeProduto que vieram da tela com os do banco de dados, quando um determinado registro não vier da tela, é porquê ele foi removido, então é só fazer um delete.

**Adição de um ItemPedidoDeProduto**

Se um ItemPedidoDeProduto vier da tela sem o id, significa que é um novo registro, então será necessário apenas fazer a inserção.

As alterações no Pedido tem que ser [atômicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) (devem ser realizadas na mesma transação) pois creio que por exemplo, você terá que validar se uma determinada quantidade de produtos existem em estoque.

Answer (score 1):

**Usando uma variável auxiliar ao teu favor**

Cria uma lista que define o comportamento que deve ser feito no próprio JSON, em cada registro.

Todo registro previamente enviado teria, por exemplo, 0, dizendo que é um dado pré-existente não alterado.

Inseriu um novo registro? Atribui um outro valor, como por exemplo, 1. Aí o servidor sabe que tem que executar um `INSERT INTO`

Excluiu um registro? Opa, mas o cara pode ter excluído algo que que nem está no servidor ainda... então basicamente

```
se(action = 0)entao
  definir action deste registro 2, para executar DELETE do lado do servidor
senao
  só apaga do JSON, não envia pro servidor
```

A mesma coisa vale pra uma edição. Se a pessoa editar um registro que ainda não foi inserido no servidor você vai manter o 1, mas vai atualizar os dados dentro do JSON. Se o registro existia previamente aí você define um 3, pra que seja executado um `UPDATE` no banco.

Isso vai te evitar ter que ficar fazendo 1 `SELECT` pra cada registro, aumenta quase nada o esforço do lado cliente, diminui muito o problema do lado do servidor. (Você só vai ter que adicionar um switch na parte servidor se ela já está pronta)

Se quiser reduzir mais ainda o problema do lado do servidor, você pode tentar filtrar o JSON e enviar tudo que não é 0, para que o servidor seja encarregado somente de alterar o banco, e não ter que ficar verificando quais registros foram ou não afetados.

Comment: A solução funciona, mas variável auxiliar não tem nada haver com a definição do objeto de negócio dele. Imagine que ele queira promover o reuso da interface e do objeto de negócio dele para exposição em um webservice, quem for consumir o serviço deveria apenas se preocupar com o nome do método e com as propriedades que definem o objeto, ele não deveria se preocupar com variável auxiliar que não faz parte da abstração :o)

Comment: @wryel O principal ponto pelo que entendi do problema dele é como passar pro banco e o que fazer pra não sair dando `UPDATE` em tudo. A variável extra pode não ter nada haver com o DAO, mas nada impede de que somente esta rotina faça uso disso, e além do mais, se outras telas funcionarem desse jeito, ele pode montar um mini framework. Um sistema desse tipo tem que evitar ao máximo overhead do lado do servidor. A minha sugestão não é mais limpa, mas é a "mais rápida". Se você não cria facilitadores, você cria gargalos no servidor só porque não quis uma variável auxiliar.

Answer (score 0):

Então, eu já fiz um sistema de orçamento, e para alterar individualmente, você tem que fazer um form para cada linha, interessante também fazer um botão submit individual para cada um também, tanto de excluir quanto pra alterar. 
Ai vai poder fazer o que quiser com os dados do post, você pode se esforçar um pouco mais e fazer com AJAX, a aplicação fica muito melhor, sem reload, se já não usa.
Ai, a partir do POST, pode alterar no banco.
Respondendo suas perguntas, para alterar no banco só com UPDATE mesmo, método mais simples e rápido.
Não precisa excluir todas as informações, só alterar a linha que desejar, como já disse antes.

Answer (score 0):

Com o `UPDATE`, é mais rápido pois os dados estão sendo reescritos nas linhas já existentes. Com o `DELETE` você teria que apagar e depois inserir novamente e isso toma mais tempo, linhas de código e desempenho. Além disso você pode usar a instrução de `MULTI_QUERY` do PHP (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) com o `UPDATE` para atualizar todos os dados com uma requisição e melhorar ainda mais a performance.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisa fazer ter pouco de conhecimento em jquery/js.

1° Cria 2 variáveis array.

```
var deleteID = new Array();
var updateID = new Array();
```

2° Você vai fazer criar um evento onchange em todas campos do grid, que quando for alterado vai inserir dentro do array a seguinte key , campo = value,

3 ° Quando você for fazer uma alteração no produto o onchange vai enviar para array updateID com ID do produto e o campo que for supostamente alterado exemplo Quantidade:20.

4 ° Para deletar você vai criar um botão de deletar X em cada linha da tabela e inserir um botão com ação onclick='deletarProduto(iddoproduto)' ou pode fazer checkbox;
dentro da função você adicionar assim

```
function deletarProduto(iddoproduto) {
    deleteID.push(iddoproduto);
}
```

No final você vai ter botão Salvar/Atualizar nessa ação você envia os dados das 2 Arrays para o backend.
Aí a lógica vai ser mais ou menos assim.

```
<?php
  $acao_deletar = $_POST['deletar'];
  $acao_update  = $_POST['update'];

  // Se existir alguma ação de deletar 
  if(!isset($acao_deletar) {
     $deletar_ids = implode(",",$acao_deletar);
     mysql_query("DELETE FROM tb_produto WHERE ID IN (".$deletar_ids.")");
  }

  // Se existir alguma ação de update 
  if(!isset($acao_update) {
     foreach($acao_update as $update) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE FROM tb_produto SET $update[campo] = $update[valor] WHERE ID = $update[id]");
     }
  }


?>
```

esse código encima é só exemplo para abrir um pouco sua mente espero ter ajudado.